# Oracle CURSOR%ROWTYPE common for many cursors having only some columns the same

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Good day, I have a couple of tables ITEMS_* that may have different columns but certain columns exists and are of the same type in all of them. An example:

```
CREATE TABLE "APT"."ITEMS_AV" (
    -- These columns are common for all tables
    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CODE" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    -- Other columns may differ
    ...,
    -- The primary key is the same in all tables
    CONSTRAINT "ITEMS_AV_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
) TABLESPACE "APT" ;
```

For each table I wrote a special PL/SQL procedure to process data in the table. There's a cursor 'cur' declared in each procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE PROCESS_ITEMS_AV AS
    CURSOR cur IS
        SELECT ID, CODE, DESCRIPTION, ...
        FROM ITEMS_AV;
BEGIN
    FOREACH d IN cur LOOP
        FIX_DATA(d);
        -- Continue processing 'row' data
        ...
    END LOOP
END PROCESS_ITEMS_AV;
```

Inside this procedure I need to call procedure FIX_DATA that fixes data in the current row. For example remove whitespaces from row.CODE and remove invalid characters from row.DESCRIPTION. Normally I'd declare this procedure for each single table as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE FIX_DATA (r IN OUT ITEMS_AV%ROWTYPE) AS 
BEGIN
    r.CODE := ...;
    r.DESCRIPTION := ...;
END TESTPROC;
```

BUT this procedure does the same for all tables so I'd like to have just single procedure FIX_DATA which would be used in all PROCESS_ITEMS_* procedures. The problem is the table name in the declaration of parameter 'r':

```
PROCEDURE FIX_DATA (r IN OUT ITEMS_AV%ROWTYPE) AS ...
```

Is there a way how to declare the 'r' parameter so that I can use it for many cursors which have only some (but allways the same) columns identical?

Many thanks in advance.
Vojtech

Comment: I Suggest Instead of Sending a row at a time, Pass a column to your Fix Data.
Which requires one more iteration in Process_items_av procedure

Comment: I considered doing it this way but if I needed to fix more columns in future I'd have to change FIX_DATA procedure and all PROCESS_ITEMS_* procedures. Therefore I'd rather pass a row as it would require change FIX_DATA proc only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a generic `rowtype`. Unless you want to pass a ref cursor and handle the data manipulation through `dbms_sql`, the closest I can think of is to create an object type and populate and pass that:

```
create type fix_data_obj is object(col1 varchar2(1),
  col2 number,
  col3 date,
  constructor function fix_data_obj return self as result);
/

create type body fix_data_obj is
  constructor function fix_data_obj return self as result is
  begin
    return;
  end;
end;
/
```

The object has all the common columns defined, and if you have to handle any more columns you can add them to the object.

```
create procedure fix_data (obj in out fix_data_obj) is
begin
  obj.col1 := 'Y';
  /* and other columns */
end fix_data;
/
```

`fix_data` can then accept and update the object; again if more columns are added they just need to be handled here.

```
create procedure process_dual is
  cursor c is select * from dual;
  tmp_obj fix_data_obj := fix_data_obj();
begin
  for r in c loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Original value: ' || r.dummy);
    tmp_obj.col1 := r.dummy;
    fix_data(tmp_obj);
    r.dummy := tmp_obj.col1;
    dbms_output.put_line('Fixed value: ' || r.dummy);
  end loop;
end process_dual;
/
```

This is the painful part. You'd need to populate the relevant columns in the object from your cursor, and then update your cursor from the object after calling `fix_data`. But, if a new column was added to the object, existing processing procedures wouldnt' need to be modified, except those that have the relevant column. So that minimises the impact of a new column, at least.

```
exec process_dual;

anonymous block completed
Original value: X
Fixed value: Y
```

This would be a bit neater if you had all the procedures in a package, then you could have a record type declared in the package too rather than a standalone object type.

Getting data into and out of the object/record is still going to be the unpleasant part. You could have a procedure (or rather, procedures, one converting each way) that does that, where you pass the object/record and individual columns; then if a new column is added, overload that procedure so existing calls aren't affected.

```
create procedure cols_to_obj(obj in out fix_data_obj, col1 in varchar2,
  col2 in number, col3 in date) is
begin
  obj.col1 := col1;
  obj.col2 := col2;
  obj.col3 := col3;
end cols_to_obj;
/

create procedure obj_to_cols(obj in fix_data_obj, col1 in out varchar2,
  col2 in out number, col3 in out date) is
begin
  col1 := obj.col1;
  col2 := obj.col2;
  col3 := obj.col3;
end obj_to_cols;
/

create or replace procedure process_dual is
  cursor c is select * from dual;
  tmp_obj fix_data_obj := fix_data_obj();
  null_number number;
  null_date date;
begin
  for r in c loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Original value: ' || r.dummy);
    cols_to_obj(tmp_obj, r.dummy, null, null);
    fix_data(tmp_obj);
    /* can't just pass null for missing fields */
    obj_to_cols(tmp_obj, r.dummy, null_number, null_date);
    dbms_output.put_line('Fixed value: ' || r.dummy);
  end loop;
end process_dual;
/
```

That's going to be neater in a package too. Or you could pass individual columns straight to `fix_data`, and overload *that* if new columns are added later.

Separate `fix_*` procedures for each column might end up being easier, unless you have fixes that depend on values from more than one column.